# How to override an interface property with an inherited type

Tags: c#, interface

I'm having a hard time describing to problem in the title, sorry if the title isn't the clearest.

Suppose I have the following interface/classes :

```
public interface IAction { /*...*/ }

public class WriteAction : IAction { /*...*/ }
public class ReadAction : IAction { /*...*/ }
```

Now, these actions will be used in other classes. `ReadWriteTest` can have both `ReadAction` and `WriteAction` objects, but `ReadTest` can only have `ReadAction` objects.
Note that these test objects do more than just this, I'm redacting other functionalities as they are not pertinent to the question.

Both `xxxTest` classes share a common interface. So the implementation of the interface and `ReadWriteTest` class is as follows:

```
public interface ITest 
{ 
    List<IAction> Actions { get; set; }
}

public class ReadWriteTest : ITest
{
    public List<IAction> Actions { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that for the `ReadTest` class, I would like to limit this property to only contain `ReadAction` elements.

What I tried to implement is the following:

```
public class ReadTest : ITest
{
    public List<ReadAction> Actions { get; set; }
}
```

It seems to me that this should work, as every `ReadAction` inherently implements the `IAction` interface.

However, the compiler doesn't like it, and tells me the `ReadTest` class doesn't implement all needed `IAction` properties.

Is there a way to restrict the content of this Actionlist in the `ReadTest` class definition?

I can work around it by creating a custom `AddAction(IAction action)` method that simply does not add any `WriteAction` objects, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution to this problem.

Is this possible?

**Update on the final result**

As answered, it can be done by adding a generic type to the interface. This solves the problem I'm describing, but sadly does not solve the larger problem. Adding this generict type means that I now can't address either Test object as an `ITest`, as I'm now required to specify the generic parameter, which is different for either Test.

The solution (or at least, *my* solution) is to remove the `Actions` property from the `ITest` interface. The `Actions` properties still exist in the classes.
Instead of having the list property defined in the interface, I added a `Run()` method to the interface. This method will iterate over the locally defined `Actions` list in either Test class.

So as a quick overview:

```
foreach(ITest myTest in myTests)
{
    myTest.Run()
}
```

Class implementation for `ReadWriteTest`:

```
public List<IAction> Actions {get; set;}

public void Run()
{
    foreach(IAction action in Actions) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Class implementation for `ReadTest`:

```
public List<ReadAction> Actions {get; set;}

public void Run()
{
    foreach(IAction action in Actions) //I could also declare it as a ReadAction. Either works.
    { /*...*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can accept changing the interface so that you can't set the actions directly via the property, then you can make the class covariant by using the `out` keyword.

This will then allow you to create, for example, an object of type `ReadWriteTest` and pass it to a method which accepts a parameter of type `ITest<IAction>`.

Here's a complete compilable console app to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    // The basic IAction interface.

    public interface IAction
    {
        void Execute();
    }

    // Some sample implementations of IAction.

    public sealed class ReadAction: IAction
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ReadAction");
        }
    }

    public sealed class ReadWriteAction: IAction
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ReadWriteAction");
        }
    }

    public sealed class GenericAction: IAction
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GenericAction");
        }
    }

    // The base ITest interface. 'out T' makes it covariant on T.

    public interface ITest<out T> where T: IAction
    {
        IEnumerable<T> Actions
        {
            get;
        }
    }

    // A ReadWriteTest class.

    public sealed class ReadWriteTest: ITest<ReadWriteAction>
    {
        public ReadWriteTest(IEnumerable<ReadWriteAction> actions)
        {
            _actions = actions;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ReadWriteAction> Actions
        {
            get
            {
                return _actions;
            }
        }

        private readonly IEnumerable<ReadWriteAction> _actions;
    }

    // A ReadTest class.

    public sealed class ReadTest: ITest<ReadAction>
    {
        public ReadTest(IEnumerable<ReadAction> actions)
        {
            _actions = actions;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ReadAction> Actions
        {
            get
            {
                return _actions;
            }
        }

        private readonly IEnumerable<ReadAction> _actions;
    }

    // A GenericTest class.

    public sealed class GenericTest: ITest<IAction>
    {
        public GenericTest(IEnumerable<IAction> actions)
        {
            _actions = actions;
        }

        public IEnumerable<IAction> Actions
        {
            get
            {
                return _actions;
            }
        }

        private readonly IEnumerable<IAction> _actions;
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            // This demonstrates that we can pass the various concrete classes which have
            // different IAction types to a single test method which has a parameter of
            // type ITest<IAction>.

            var readActions = new[]
            {
                new ReadAction(),
                new ReadAction()
            };

            var test1 = new ReadTest(readActions);
            test(test1);

            var readWriteActions = new[]
            {
                new ReadWriteAction(),
                new ReadWriteAction(),
                new ReadWriteAction()
            };

            var test2 = new ReadWriteTest(readWriteActions);
            test(test2);

            var genericActions = new[]
            {
                new GenericAction(),
                new GenericAction(),
                new GenericAction(),
                new GenericAction()
            };

            var test3 = new GenericTest(genericActions);
            test(test3);
        }

        // A generic test method.

        private static void test(ITest<IAction> data)
        {
            foreach (var action in data.Actions)
            {
                action.Execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to set the actions after creating the objects, you can add to each concrete class a setter method.

For example, you could change the `ReadWriteTest` class to:

```
public sealed class ReadWriteTest: ITest<ReadWriteAction>
{
    public void SetActions(IEnumerable<ReadWriteAction> actions)
    {
        _actions = actions;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ReadWriteAction> Actions
    {
        get
        {
            return _actions;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<ReadWriteAction> _actions = Enumerable.Empty<ReadWriteAction>();
}
```

Comment: If I understand your (superb!) answer correctly, using the `out` keyword on a generic type T allows T to automatically be cast to any of its inherited types or implemented interfaces? Also, if I don't add a `set` to the interface property, shouldn't I still be able to actually add a `set` to the actual classes that implement the interface? If I e.g. only have a `get` on my interface property (e.g. `string Name {get;}`), I can still implement a `set` on the actual class (e.g. `public string Name {get;set;}`), or is this not possible in the case of using an `out` keyword?

Comment: @Flater The answer is "kindof". It's actually quite complicated and has to do with the fact that you are only using the type T as outputs. I can't explain all about it here, but [here's a Microsoft article about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

Comment: You could essentially do the same with my answer by adding `out` to `ITest`, changing the `List` into `IEnumerable` and making the property read only.

Answer (score 6):

You could fix this by using a generic type in your `ITest` interface:

```
public interface ITest<T> where T : IAction
{ 
    List<T> Actions { get; set; }
}
```

Note the type constraint which forces the passed in type to be `IAction`. This in turn makes your subclasses this:

```
public class ReadWriteTest : ITest<IAction>
{
    public List<IAction> Actions { get; set; }
}

public class ReadTest : ITest<ReadAction>
{
    public List<ReadAction> Actions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But of course then you can't pass a `ReadWriteTest` object to a method expecting an `ITest<IAction>` object.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Why not?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Perhaps I'm confused, but you are saying that `void SomeFunc(ITest<IAction> input)` will conflict with `SomeFunc(new ReadWriteTest());`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ReadTest`: Try this: First, get your code sample above to compile (by adding the missing types) and then add this line of code: `ITest<IAction> test = new ReadTest();` - It will give a compile error along the lines of "Cannot implicitly convert type 'ReadTest' to 'ITest<IAction>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" (Note: It *will* work with `ReadWriteTest` because that implements `ITest<IAction>`, but `ReadTest` doesn't.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: While that is a valid point, I'm not going to use it like that. @DavidG: Thanks, that seems to be what I need! Just for clarity, that does mean that if I want to address ReadTest's `Actions` property as a `List<IAction>` (my goal is to address either Test class as an ITest object), I'm going to have to cast it? Or does the compiler autocast it?

Comment: @Flater A `List<ReadAction>` is not assignable to a `List<IAction>` so you will be unable to pass `ReadTest.ReadAction` to a method expecting a `List<IAction>`. And casting will give a runtime error.

Comment: Update to my comment: No, it doesn't allow casting of the `Actions` property if I intend to pass the list itself. However, it does work in a `foreach(IAction action in myReadTest.Actions)`, which is how I intend to use it. So for my needs, it's perfect. Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: @Flater Yes, that works because [`IEnumerable<T>` is covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) and `foreach` uses `IEnumerable<T>` to iterate the collection.

Comment: Using a generic in the interface does prevent me from referring to either test simply as `ITest`, since I now need to specify the generic type. So I still can't iteratively address either test by using `ITest`. However, this is a problem with my initial goals, not with your solution, so I'm keeping your answer. I'm going to remove the `Actions` property from the interface, and will use a method in the interface, so I can keep addressing either Test object in a uniform way.

Comment: @Flater For comparison, I'm going to post an answer that might be of interest (although maybe not quite what you want). One minute...